# AG-GRID forEachNode only operates on a limited number of buffered rows

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

If I add a `console.log()` to my code below, I can see that it is correctly printing all of the rows in the gird, I can expand them in developer console and see the data is there.

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode((rowNode, index) => {
    rowNode.setSelected(false);
});
```

however, this exact code when I am telling it to do `rowNode.setSelected(false);`  , it only operates on the limited number of rows around 20 or so which is the default `rowBuffer`  on the grid.
If the data is there because I can see it with a `console.log`,  then why it cannot delete **all** the rows? It only deletes the buffered ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all rows and delete all selected rows:-

```
 deletedAllSelectedRows() {
          this.gridApi.selectAll(); //select all rows
          const sel = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
          this.gridApi.applyTransaction({remove: sel});
      }
```

> Note:-  version 23.1.0 is required for `applyTransaction`. For lower
> version    use  `updateRowData()`

Comment: Tried to follow your example but couldn't , I asked why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167125/ag-grid-does-not-an-applytransaction-method-on-gridapi

Comment: Accept this as answer, if it helped.