# AG-GRID does not an applyTransaction method on gridApi

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

This is my `onGridReady()` method:

```
onGridReady = (grid) => {
    this.gridInstance = grid;
    this.resizeColumnsToFit();
    this.props.setIsLoading(false);
    this.gridApi = grid.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = grid.columnApi;
    console.log("gridOptions is", this.gridOptions);
};
```

then in a button click I have:

```
const sel = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
console.log(sel); // this one is good.
const res = this.gridApi.applyTransaction({ remove: sel }); // this one is not good
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this.gridApi.applyTransaction is not a function
```

I tried to follow their own example from here: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-transactions/

What is it I am doing wrong then?

Comment: console.log(sel);  What you are getting here?

Comment: @Mahi I get the info about each selected row which is the 16 columns I have with values in each one. so like the values of each column for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version 23.1.0 is required for `applyTransaction`

check `sel` exists then:-

```
this.gridApi?.applyTransaction({ remove: sel });
```

version lower than 23.1.0, use

```
this.gridApi?.updateRowData({ remove: sel })
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=23.1.0

Comment: what's the point , ok it won't crash if it is not there but our problem is why I can't call it , not why it crashes when I call it. I want to call it but it doesn't find that method.

Comment: Can you update which modules you are  using and version no.

Comment: Looks Like it is version 21.1.1 for me